# Can I store image files in firebase using Java API

Tags: java, android, firebase

Is there any way to store image files in firebase using Java api?

Comment: How do you convert back in to a Bitmap?

Comment: @Binghammer it's simple.

    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imageFile, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

Comment: *Firebase just released a new feature called [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). This allows you to upload images and other non-JSON data to a dedicated storage service. We highly recommend that you use this for storing images, instead of storing them as base64 encoded data in the JSON database.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using this snippet:

```
Bitmap bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.chicken);//your image
ByteArrayOutputStream bYtE = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bYtE);
bmp.recycle();
byte[] byteArray = bYtE.toByteArray();
String imageFile = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and for retrieving

```
public Bitmap stringToBitMap(String encodedString){
   try {
      byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
      Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
      return bitmap;
   } catch(Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: How about displaying image from imageFile string?

Comment: The following should help you with displaying the encoded string as bitmap.
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageFileString, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);