# Can I store image files in firebase using Java API?

Tags: android, firebase, java

Is there any way to store image files in firebase using Java api to be used for android application?

I have read this thread [Can I store image files in firebase using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292969/can-i-store-image-files-in-firebase-using-java-api) and still there is no answer. I know that there is an official api for it, called firepano here is the link https://github.com/firebase/firepano but it is for Javascript library.

is there any solution for Java library??

Comment: All the firepano library does is base64 encode the image and store it in a Firebase node. You can easily replicate that in Java. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used this code and now it's working:

```
  Bitmap bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.chicken);//your image
ByteArrayOutputStream bYtE = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bYtE);
bmp.recycle();
byte[] byteArray = bYtE.toByteArray();
String imageFile = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Sounds good. Don't forget to accept your answer (that will probably be allowed in a few days), so that it's clear that the question has been addressed (and to gain some reputation points).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is It recommended though ? To upload images in Firebase ? Is it really meant to useful in that way ? Or direct upload on S3 bucket would be more preferable ? I use firebase for shopping list app, and I want to include image support. Thus asking!