# How do you save a file to a Firebase Hosting folder location for images through android?

Tags: android, file, save, firebase, retrofit

I'm really new to Firebase and am studying how to implement it right now. I was thinking that it has functions similar to Parse where a ParseFile object can be created that holds the file and then has functions to upload it something like the following :

```
ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile(file);
parseFile.saveInBackground();
```

If you have suggestions and/or working solutions do post them as they will be exceptionally useful.

I am also studying about RetroFit as it has a great way of sending MultiPartPost requests and if ever could be tied up with Firebase I just can't find the connection yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting is a service for hosting static assets, typically the HTML/CSS/images of a web site. You cannot programmatically add files to Firebase Hosting.

The Firebase Database allows you to store JSON data. While binary data is not a type that is supported in JSON, it is possible to encode the binary data in say base64 and thus store the image in a (large) string. See [Can I store image files in firebase using Java API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538704/can-i-store-image-files-in-firebase-using-java-api) Note that while this is possible, it is not recommended for anything but small images or as a curiosity to see that it can be done.

Your best option is typically to store the images on a 3rd party image storage service.

Comment: I see. Could you please recommend a service that is fast to set up and is the best for scenarios like this? I'd imagine a system whereas I'd have key-for-value storage for images - hence being able to store an image ID in Firebase and do a query in the other service to find the corresponding image

Comment: Sorry. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."