# Firebase - How to store .obj file?

Tags: firebase, cloud, storage

I try to simple cloud example. I use firebase for data storage. [This guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html) says that how to store string or string list. Hosting shows to load image files. How to store .obj or other files?

Comment: Firebase is a JSON database. JSON doesn't have a data type for images nor for .obj files. The only way you can store those in Firebase is by encoding them into a supported type, typically a base64 encoded string. This topic is covered regularly and has been covered very recently here. I'm going to mark as a duplicate.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054575/can-i-store-image-on-firebase-as-file-instead-of-a-dataurl, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292969/can-i-store-image-files-in-firebase-using-java-api, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538704/can-i-store-image-files-in-firebase-using-java-api